# SQL Server backup collation issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation

I was given SQL Server 2005 backup with collation set to : **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI**

When I select any data it looks like the data is saved in different collation , for example :

*user : "Micha³" - which should be "Michał" and so on*

I've tried converting tables and database to one of Polish collation, also tried *select* with collate but it still looks the same.

Have anyone had similar issue and knows what actually is going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make long story short, the collation didn't have much to do with this issue, the other application that saved the data did that using some mixed-up encoding and I found out that they weren't able to display the data properly themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Collation (sorting order) implies *character encoding* (mapping characters to bytes) - did you try using Unicode (utf-8, utf-16)? In a pinch, Latin-2 (a.k.a. ISO-8859-2, Central European single-byte charset) may be what you're looking for.

In other words, Latin-1 is a single-byte character encoding for Western-European languages, but it can't store characters from Central-European (or other) languages.

See also [this for a longer explanation of charsets, collations, and other headaches](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: @Martin: Ah yes, I'm nitpicking too much - the given collations only make sense in a single character encoding, so choosing a collation implies a character encoding. Edited.

Comment: That make sense , but it's not that I can't update those fields with Central European character string literals, because I can. What is bothering me is why backup that I retrieve is not showing those letter in appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

You say "when I select ...". Where are the query results being displayed?